# Docker container running gMSA whilst having admin permissions

Tags: active-directory, docker, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to set up a Docker container for our DevOps pipelines. I've... almost got it all.

Right now I've got a Windows-based container which:

1. has pre-installed SDKs, Java and the like
2. can manipulate (start, stop, build) docker containers
3. can access our network shares

The problem is that I can't get points 2) and 3) to be available simultaneously. To enable 3) I've had to [prepare a group managed service account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/manage-serviceaccounts) and the docker container needs to run as the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`. However, when the container IS running as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` it seems to lose access to the Docker pipeline.

Any idea how I can get both these things to work at the same time?

Comment: Normally, if a process running under the Network Service accesses a file share, it does so in the context of the "computer" account.  If this is network service in a container , I'm not sure what context it runs under when it comes out of the container host.  Have you checked the security logs to see which access was attempted, and then adjusted the ACL of the share accordingly?

Comment: @Semicolon gSMA was set up and a credential spec file is provided to get share access (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/gmsa-run-container). But, AFAIK, NETWORK SERVICE has to be used to get gSMA to work -> in turn prevents docker pipe access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` isn't the only account that will work with gMSA - it can be another `NT AUTHORITY` account, such as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` (which does have permission to handle docker containers).